# How to restore a dump database backup for a Django project with existing models and migrations?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, mysql-python

Setting up a mysql database from an existing dump is very easy

```
# open prompt cd into the directory where the dump is located
# login to mysql
create database mydb
use mydb
source mydb.sql
```

And all is done!
But the problem comes with Django. Django has troubles with existing schemes and data that have not been created from models and migration system. And in Django, everything must come from models and migrations.

I perfectly know that I have this option

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

But this is only suitable when creating a blank new Django project using existing database.

What if I want to run an existing Django project to another machine and the Django project uses a database? The project already has existing models with some manage=false set, I cannot simply inspectdb it. And if I restore the database outside Django, the Django ORM will no longer recognize it.

Then what is the correct way to restore a database from a database backup for a project with existing models and migrations?

Comment: if I'm reading this right, is the question: how to dump an existing database?

Answer (score 0):

If the database that you are restoring was previously managed by django, you should encounter no problems simply restoring the database with your three-step process.  Django's migration history is stored as a table in any database that it manages.  As long as that table makes it over, your new migrations going forward should work fine.